# Vide.js: Change menu title

Tags: php, jquery, flash, video, video.js

I have video.js plugin for streaming videos and I want to change title in select language menu.

```
http://pokit.org/get/img/ed8bb4b0a13769a3105b1b9111c2b635.jpg
```

I want to change "CAPTIONS" into "Languages".How can I do that ??

Comment: Can you post some code please? :)

Comment: It's a plugin so I think that you can't answer the question if you don't know really good this plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it. Here are the lines 4307-4310 of `video.js` version 3.2.0 (right after the separator "Captions Button"):

```
menu.el.appendChild(_V_.createElement("li", {
   className: "vjs-menu-title",
   innerHTML: _V_.uc(this.kind)
}));
```

Change to:

```
menu.el.appendChild(_V_.createElement("li", {
   className: "vjs-menu-title",
   innerHTML: "Languages"
}));
```

See the picture:

http://i46.tinypic.com/ir53sg.png